# gfortran compiling issue with double complex variable

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, double, gfortran, complex-numbers

I've been trying to compile a programme and have run into a simple-looking problem. However, I haven't been able to solve it yet. Any ideas are very much appreciated. The programme looks like the following,

Code:

```
  subroutine rescal(zy,nvar)

  integer nvar,i, nexponent
  double complex zy(nvar)
  double precision maxabs, scalfac

  maxabs = 0.d0
  do i = 1, nvar
    maxabs = max(zabs(zy),maxabs)
  enddo
```

maxabs((rank 0)) should store the max of `zy` and `maxabs`. Simple, right?

I try to compile this programme with gfortran and getting the following error. I don't understand as to why the compiler is complaining that `maxabs` should be rank 1 and not rank 0. To my understanding, `zabs` is the right function to use with a double precision complex number.

```
gfortran -e -Ofast -ffixed-line-length-none -std=legacy -c -o rescal.o rescal.f
rescal.f:13.8:

maxabs = max(zabs(zy),maxabs)
1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
make: *** [rescal.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` is an elemental function which, given an array argument returns an array result.  Your problem here, then, is that `zabs(zy)` is an array.

Simply, you are missing selecting an element of `zy` as you loop through:

```
do i = 1, nvar
  maxabs = max(zabs(zy(i)),maxabs)  ! Select the i-th element of zy
enddo
```

That said, a couple of points:

- you can avoid non-standard specific `zabs` by using the generic `abs`;
- the `maxval` function is available.

You can instead have

```
maxabs = MAXVAL(ABS(zy))
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I must have been blind as a bat not to see the index. Thanks again!